# Android HTTP GET Request

Tags: java, android, python, http, httprequest

I've created a Python REST api with Flask, which 'should' allow me to use my phone as a Keyboard.

If I go to 'http://192.168.0.37:5000/keyboard/a' on my phones web browser, my laptop will enter the letter a. (This works).

I've tried to create an Android app that will make the http request, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is the code I used. I've tested it with in a basic Java file and it works, but it won't work in an Android Application.

```
private void sendGet(String letter) throws IOException {
    URL keyB = new URL("http://192.168.0.37:5000/keyboard/" + letter);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), keyB.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    URLConnection kb = keyB.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            kb.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        a.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), a.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Is there any errors while running the code?

Comment: You have to use a thread for network related task, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: Might it be related to who has access to that URL? e.g. If I click the link, nothing happens... Can you make that request from Postman and does it still work?

Comment: @SJoshi It should of worked, 192.168 is my LAN, I'll try threads now Remees

Comment: @RemeesMSyde Putting this into an AsyncTask worked. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RemeesMSyde comment.

I put the method into an AsyncTask and it now works.

This is the code I have used.

```
class SendKeyStroke extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... letter) {
        try {
            URL keyB = new URL("http://192.168.0.37:5000/keyboard/" + letter[0]);
            System.out.println(keyB.toString());

            URLConnection kb = keyB.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kb.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

            String inputLine;
            StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                a.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch(Exception ex) {

        }

        return null;
    }
}
```